# React native returning null for state

Tags: react-native, components, states, prop, setstate

I am trying to set the state of an item then use the new state as a prop which is passed to my component but it doesn't appear to be setting the state in time

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.cartFirebase = firebaseApp.database().ref('carts')
    this.cartFirebase.child(DeviceInfo.getUniqueID() + '/items').push({
      item: this.props.data.name,
      qty: 1
    }).then((snap) => {
      this.state = {
        cartKey: snap.key
      }
    })
  }
```

Component

```
<AddToCartRow item={this.props.data.sizes} option='size' key={this.state.cartKey}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because at the time of rendering `AddToCartRow`, `this.state.cartKey` is `null`.

You're setting `cartKey` from within a Promise `.then(..)` which has not yet been fulfilled.

Your `render()` is actually calling before your `constructor` has populated `this.state.cartKey`.

You could write the following logic to only render the component when `this.state.cartKey` evaluates to true, and as we know `null` evaluates to `false`.

```
{this.state.cartKey && <AddToCartRow item={this.props.data.sizes} option='size' key={this.state.cartKey}/>}
```